# how to search contact from address book using uitextview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, addressbook

i'm using uitextview for searching the contact details from address book. i.e., like uisearchbar search the contact details while text edit change in uitextview.

[image: this is the image]

i'm using uitextview if i tap 'a', the list of the contacts from address book will be display in table view

please give me the solution

Comment: You will probably get more answers if you show the code that you have written, and give details about what is/is not working.

Comment: @GregInYEG: here i added the image please verify that

Comment: First, clicking on an iPhone (or any device that has no mouse) is impossible. Secondly, use ⇧⌘4 followed by pressing the Space bar when making a screenshot on your Mac. Thirdly, [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) has a message composer class. You can look in its source code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution simple coding here it is

//viewDidLoad

> ```
>   NSMutableArray *personArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>   ABRecordRef personRef;
>   for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(allPeople); i++)
>   {
>     personRef = (ABRecordID*)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
>     ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, ABRecordGetRecordID(personRef));
>     @try 
>     {
>         if (ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty))
>             [personArray addObject: (id)personRef];
>     }
>     @catch (NSException * e) 
>     {
>     }
>     @finally 
>     {
>     }
>   NSString *FirstName = [[[NSString stringWithString:(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(personRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)]stringByAppendingString:@" "]stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(personRef, kABPersonLastNameProperty)];
>     [arr addObject:FirstName];
> }
> [arr3 addObjectsFromArray:arr];
>   }
> ```

//textviewdidchange

> ```
>   [arr3 removeAllObjects];
>    NSInteger counter = 0;
>   for(NSString *name in arr)
>   {
>     NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:txtView.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];  
>     if(r.location != NSNotFound)
>     {
>          [arr3 addObject:name];
>     }
>     counter++;
> }
> [table reloadData];
> ```

Thanks for your help